# How does two client javascript files interact with each other, when the server is running separately?

Tags: javascript, django, websocket

I have created a django application. There are two different html pages, which run different scripts in each other. I want to share data between the two script files, so while I update the variables in one script, I can send the updated data to the other script file, and make the corresponding changes to the variable present in the other script file.

As I researched, one way I found to do that is to use websockets, where a regular connection is built with the django server and the client. But, it is limited to single client. So, through websockets, I can not share data between two different client pages. What other methods, can I use to share data between the two script files in the client?

Edit 1: The changes in one script file has to be reciprocated instantly or after really less time delay in the second script file.

Edit 2: The clients for the server can be running on different devices(one on phone and other on computer). Thus, having a solution to save data in localstorage doesnt work

Edit 3: I tried making api calls. The instant change in variable happens in one script file, an api call is made that makes change in the database. While, the other script is constantly making api calls at regular intervals to get the value of the variable that is saved. But, this creates a time delay, and therefore, was looking for a websocket like solution, where instead of communication between server and client, we have communication between two different clients operating in the same server

Comment: Use local storage, session storage, or cookies.

Comment: You can also use sessions on the server, or store the data in a file or database.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense when the data is changed, but in this particular case, the changes in one javascript file is happenning at really small interval and the related change has to reciprocate in the second file instantly, or in a really small time. Also, another use case for the application is the client application is running on two different devices at the same time. Thus, storing the data in local or storage wont work. I am looking for a server solution

Comment: You mean these are two different users interacting with the application, not one user moving to a different page?

Comment: The same user is interacting with the application with two different devices. In my particular case, I am using the web application to run the webcamera on his laptop, which constantly gets the pose data of the user, and sends the data to his mobile, where the pose data is used to make changes in the VR scene that runs on his mobile. The idea is to create a web VR application that runs via web apis

Comment: Websockets doens't require the client to make API calls, the server can push data to the client. The client just has to be ready to read it all the time.

Comment: Websockets is probably what most online video games use.

Comment: Exactly, I am looking for a similar solution with the clients case. Where the client on one end is sending data while the other client is ready to read the data, and make the changes accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, general design questions like this are too broad for [so]. You need to investigate it elsewhere, perhaps by looking at how other games do it. Then try to implement it, and if you can't get it working post your code.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, can you please refer me to the correct direction on how to find the best way to design a solution to this. I searched online on how to share data between two javascript files, but everywhere they asked me to use socket io, or node to do that?

Comment: You're searching for the wrong thing. It's just using websockets to send data to and from clients. The files are irrelevant.

Comment: Client 1 sends to the server, it sends to client 2, and vice versa. You don't communicate directly from one client to another.

Answer (score 0):

Use built in `window.localStorage` to store things on the clients browser for the life of the session. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage for reference.

Comment: If the files are running on different devices, this is a server problem.  I would make an API call to your server every time you need to use that shared variable, so that every time you use it, it is updated.